# Angular regex to prevent white space after name

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to introduce regex in an angular controller for name validation.  I can only have letters, forward slashes, hyphens and a single space between names.  I cannot have any white space after a string.  So "John-\ Doe" is valid, "John-\ Doe-\ Do-\e Doe" is valid but "John-\              Doe", with 2 or more spaces between words is invalid and "John-\ Doe  ", one space or more after last word, is invalid.

This is what I have so far: ^[a-zA-Z-]+( [a-zA-Z-]+)*$
My regex prevents a space between names but I am not sure how to validate for one space after the last word.  I tried: [^a-zA-Z /-]+|[\s]{2,} and that doesn't work for me.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: thanks, however, all of this is handled in the javascript, so I cannot any ngs, which is unfortunate.

Comment: I don't quite get what the problem is. You escaped a hyphen in your regex. Why? Did you want to match a backslash? Try [`/^[a-zA-Z\\-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z\\-]+)*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/yphOH1/1). Please show a string that does not get validated with this pattern and explain why.

Comment: Any feedback on my comment?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to just fix it for the user? If so, this is a good application for the trim method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

```
"John Doe ".trim() == "John Doe" // true
```

could always do a check to see if what was supplied is equal to the trimmed version.. though that is a bit sloppy.. e.g. if `"John Doe ".trim() == "John Doe"` was `false` then you know that there *were* spaces before or after.

Comment: Hi, I cannot fix it for the user, it has to be universal for all users so the .trim() will not work, unfortunately.  I actually think it is not possible to validate against white spaces after a word in my particular scenario.

Comment: Hmm okay. If I get the chance later I'll take a closer look at the question and see what I can do. good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  Much appreciated!

Comment: @Eddie take a look at the polly fill section in that MDN link. The regex pattern they used to match the spaces probably is what you want (`/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g`).

Comment: thanks, I tried that and it didn't meet the requirements.  I'll play around with it some more.  I am leaning more and more toward that this just isn't possible in my situation.